# how to Looping python scripts together

Tags: python-2.7, loops, global-variables

I have two files.   An 'initialization' script aka file1.py and a 'main code' script aka 'main_code.py'.   The main_code.py is really a several hundred line .ipynb that was converted to a .py file.   I want to run the same skeleton of the code with the only adjustment being to pass in the different parameters found in the 'file1.py' script.

In reality, it is much more complex than what I have laid out below with more references to other locations / DBs and what not.

However, I receive errors such as 'each_item[0]'  is not defined.   I can't seem to be able to pass in the values/variables  that come from my loop in file1.py to my script that is contained inside the loop.

Must be doing something very obviously wrong as I imagine this is a simple fix

file1.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import bumpy as np
import jaydebeapi as jd
#etc...

cities = ['NYC','LA','DC','MIA'] # really comes from a query/column
value_list = [5,500,5000,300]  # comes from a query/column
zipped = list(zip(cities,value_list))  # make tuples

for each_item in zipped:
      os.system('python loop_file.py')
      # where I'm getting errors.
```

main_code.py:

```
names  = each_item[0]
value = each_item[1]
# lots of things going on here in real code but for simplicity...
print value = value * 4
print value
```

Comment: Do you absolutely require main_code.py to be a separate file, or could you instead use a function? For a separate file, you could take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

Comment: The main_code.py is really an extensive 70-80 cell jupiter notebook that I want to call for reach of the parameters.   I want to be able to repeatedly run it with the different parameters that I generate elsewhere.